# Matchings and showing that elements of a set X can be labelled as elements of a collection of subsets of X.

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

I have an extension question from a textbook which hasn't got a solution and is meant to be more challenging than the other questions and so I can only make an attempt at the question and am not sure if it is correct. I've included the question:

"Consider the set $X$ of size $n$ and let $\Omega = ${$S_1,...,S_n$} be a collection of subsets of $X$, each having size at least $n/2$, where every element of $X$ belongs to at least $n/2$ sets in $\Omega$. Show that the elements of $X$ can be labelled as {$x_1,...,x_n$} $= X$ so that $x_i \in S_i$, for $i = 1,...,n$."

I was thinking that since each $S_i$ is of size at least $n/2$, and every element of $X$ is in at least $n/2$ sets in $\Omega$, we can say $|S_i| \geq n/2$ and we can define a bipartite graph $G$ and then I'm guessing the minimum degree $\delta(G)$ of $G$ will be at least $n/2$, so then $G$ contains a perfect matching.

I'm not sure how we would define the bipartite graph in order to get the perfect matching though, or if you should go this route in the first place. Anyone have any idea how they would answer this question, thanks for the help.

Comment: We can define the bipartite graph with vertex classes $X$ and $\Omega$. $x$ is connected to $S_i$ when $x \in S_i$. Then your approach works.